# Change title in ggplot legend and update marker notation

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm having trouble changing the title and the look of my legend in ggplot, right now it looks like this:
[image]

But I want the title to be "Whatever I please" and the colors representing the different data to be larger.(e.g. taking up the whole square instead of being a tiny circle)

For the title I tried changing:
`theme(legend.position="top", legend.title='Whatever I please')`

But ggplot doesn't accept this. How can I make this adjustments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot(...) + geom_point(...) + 
  labs(color = "Your title here") + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 5)))`

You may need to change the size in the guide to get the look you want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I try your solution I get `Element legend.title must be a element_text object`

Comment: I believe that error is from your code above. There's no `theme` statement in my code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for this. As an aside, setting the legend title by the colour of the label, instead of with legend.title, is exactly why I've found ggplot mapping to be such an obtuse nightmare!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `name` and `guide` arguments of the `scale_colour_discrete` function to do that:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = qsec, col = as.factor(cyl)))+ 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_colour_discrete(name = "Whatever I please",
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10)))
```

The `legend.title` argument of the theme function only accepts `element_text` values (so your 'Whatever I please' there won't work), and is used mostly to change font related aspects of the legend title, not the text itself.